# Recalling JS functions on Partial Page Refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am doing a partial page refresh on a div on my site. In that div I have some js functions I am calling to hide certain parts of the text.  This is basically so you can click on an item and cause the hidden text to slide out using jquery.

When I do the refresh, the hide() functions need to be called again which I am now doing with a callback function and I am using display:none for the css. When one clicks on an expand button I change the class to open.  The problem is that the items aren't staying open when the div refreshes.

This is the page refresh:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $("#newsWrapper").load(location.href+" #newsWrapper");
}, 5000);
```

This is the click event that changes the class.

```
$('.expand').live('click', function (event) {

    $(this).parent().next().toggle('slide');
    imgName = $(this).html();

    //change plus to minus or vice-versa
    if (imgName == '<img src="images/plus.png">') {
        $(this).html('<img src="images/minus_sign.jpg">');
        $(this).parent().parent().children('.news_detail').addClass('open');
        $(this).parent().parent().children('.news_detail').removeClass('close');

    } else {
        $(this).html('<img src="images/plus.png">');
        $(this).parent().parent().children('.news_detail').addClass('close');
        $(this).parent().parent().children('.news_detail').removeClass('open');
    }

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Can you show how you are binding handlers to events, and how you're doing the replace?  Does the page being loaded have similar elements, and you need to reattach the same handlers?

Comment: added code samples so you can see. Is there a callback function for load()?

Comment: so, I have the callback function working, but it takes a while to rehide the elements.. anyway I can do this so you don't see a flicker?